# Is there a way to add variable value for new column in Alter Table statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @VName      VARCHAR(8)

SET @VNAme = (
                          SELECT TOP 1 xyz 
                          FROM table
                          WHERE abc = something
                    )

ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD new_column VARCHAR (8)  NOT NULL DEFAULT @VName
```

Comment: I think you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: create a function and call it ..it will work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read [this post about SQL Injection](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/12/what-is-sql-injection/). ***Then*** you can use Dynamic SQL at your own risk, something like the following:

```
DECLARE @AlterSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    ALTER TABLE table_name ADD new_column 
        VARCHAR(8) 
        NOT NULL 
        DEFAULT ''' + REPLACE(@VName, '''', '''''') + ''''

EXEC (@AlterSQL)
```

If you want the expression to change over time, read akhilesh's function answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue()
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @VName      VARCHAR(8)

SET @VNAme = (
                          SELECT TOP 1 xyz 
                          FROM table
                          WHERE abc = something
                    )
  RETURN @VName
END


ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD new_column VARCHAR (8)  NOT NULL DEFAULT (dbo.GetValue())
```

For achieving that goal...you have create a function and call it...........